# Sharing internet connection from host to virtualized Ubuntu with Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 11.10 in Virtual Box installed on Windows Vista. I am having a Broadband(PPPoE) internet connection. I would like to use my internet connection inside Virtual Box in Ubuntu.
I tried with NAT but it couldn't connect. Then I tried Bridged Network, but still it is not connecting!!

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you select the correct adapter?

Comment: Select NAT and in Ubuntu, connect to wired network, that should do the trick.

Comment: @TheElectricMuffin yes!! I selected the correct adapter.

Comment: @HackToHell I selected NAT but its not working!!

Comment: Although this doesn't help for existing Virtual Boxes, I can recommend [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) for any new boxes you might want to create. It's essentially a wrapper for Virtual Box that allows you to easily customise these sorts of things.

Comment: Add a screenshot of bride mode.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that in the Network tab these two boxes are checked:

[image]

Then from inside the virtualized Ubuntu, you must connect to wired network, it should work.
You need to have installed the Guest Additions for this to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/

I hope entering the following information in `/etc/network/interfaces` file will help

```
auto eth0<br>
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a PFsense router/firewall virtual machine with two adapters, one set to bridged for the WAN and the other set to the Internal (to VirtualBox) network. Then place the Ubuntu VM on the internal network, with the PFSense box set to provide a a IP address via DHCP. This video provides a guide (though it's oriented to setting up a Windows based network): http://pc-addicts.com/how-to-install-pfsense-in-virtualbox/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install the Virtual box Guest Software in Ubuntu. Then use NAT on the Virtualbox. Since your Ubuntu version is older it may not have native support for the network adapter Virtualbox offers.